# Existing Schema Baseline and Repeatable Objects

Tags: flyway

How can I force Flyway to baseline current code version without redeploying repeatable objects?
I understand that with normal scripts you can define a baseline and it will not deploy SQL until new files appear. However that doesn't seems to be working for PACKAGES for example and Flyway does try to redeploy.

To give a background, I want to put existing database under source control and Flyway, but I don't want to redeploy existing objects so I would like first to initialize Flyway and capture current state of objects (baseline it). So it will deploy code that only changed after the baseline has been issued.

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'repeatable objects'? (for my own culture).

Comment: By that I mean object which can be deployed more than once without a error e.g. VIEWS , PACKAGES (CREATE OR REPLACE clause).